# Catching error on input validation

Tags: python

I need to add an error message if the user enters a string instead of an integer in my menu selection, and also amounts that the user input as data. I tried this code but it doesn't work.

```
import sys
try:
    newamount=int(input('Enter the new amount:'))
except ValueError:
    print ("error")
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Two things: you don't need to import sys to use input() or raw_input(), and if you are using python 2.7.x, please do not use input() for string input from users, use raw_input(). input() evaluates the code passed to it, so if you do this a malicious user could do something like "import os; os.system("rm -rf /")" or something equally dangerous and blow up your system. input() is ONLY safe in python 3.x, NEVER use it in python 2.7.x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TypeError` would be raised if the parameter to `int()` was of the wrong type.

Assuming you are using Python3, the return value of `input()` will always be type `str`

`ValueError` is raised if the *type* is ok, but the content isn't able to be converted to an `int`.

To ask over and over, you should use a `while` loop

```
while True:
    try:
        newamount=int(input('Enter the new amount:'))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print ("error")
```

If you want to keep count of the errors, use `itertools.count` and a `for` loop

```
from itertools import count
for c in count():
    try:
        newamount=int(input('Enter the new amount:'))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print ("error", c)
```

Comment: ya its python 3 and hw do i fix this?

Comment: @user2912389, the error you mention in the comments of alKid's answer it not from the code you have here. It's because of the way you are using the variable in a function. You should ask a new question and post the full code there.

Comment: @user2912389, do you still have a problem after replacing `TypeError` with `ValueError`?

Comment: How does it crash? Do you mean you want to ask over and over until they enter an integer?

Comment: @user2912389, ok You need a while loop. I added it to my answer

Comment: (new one)it works can you help me with this?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19557611/how-to-export-data-from-csv-as-a-list

Answer (score 2):

That's because passing an invalid string (not a number) to `int()` will raise a `ValueError`, and not `TypeError`. You're close though.

Just change it and it should work great.

```
except ValueError:
    print('Error!')
```

If you want to do something with the `newamount` variable, i suggest you to do it in the `try` block:

```
try:
    newamount=int(input('Enter the new amount:'))
    tempfunction = amount + newamount
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: tempfunction = amount + newamount                                   # adding new amount to the previous amount
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'newamount' referenced before assignment
>>>

Comment: In your try statement?

Comment: i'm trying to ask user to input amounts and if user enter any strings i need to print error and re appear the newamount=int(input('Enter the new amount:'))

Answer (score 1):

I think its better to use raw_input in these cases where the input is to be eval manually.
It goes like this...

```
s = raw_input()
try:
    choice = int(s)
except ValueError:
print ('Wrong Input!')
```

Comment: Given the parens on `print`, he's likely using Python3 which doesn't have `raw_input` (`input` has the old `raw_input` behavior)

Comment: ya python 3 .what are differentes should i do?

Comment: But thats not the case we can use parenthesis even in earlier version of python. here is the proof.. Python 2.4.3 (#1, Oct 23 2012, 22:02:41) 
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-54)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print('hi')
hi

Comment: Yep. But it isn't needed, and it's unlikely anyone would do that for printing *string*.

Comment: I am not a mind reader to alKid to know what version he is using unless he specifies it :)