# Printing list-of-lists in tabular form in Python

Tags: python

I have a list formatted like the following:

```
list_of_DVDsuppliers=[["a","m",15],["w","p",34]]
```

I'd like to print out the contents of this list as a table with some headers. Here's what I've tried so far:

```
def dvdprintsoftlist():
    print(list_of_DVDsoftwears)
    ''' printing the available DVDstocks,supplier's details '''
    print("This is your current list of stock")
    print("Supplier Name      Softwear Name             Amount")
    print("----------------------------------------------------------------")
    for (index,[name,softname,amount]) in enumerate (list_of_DVDsuppliers):
        print(name + "          " +softname + "            " +str(amount)  + "   ")
        print("----------------------------------------------------------------")
    print("")
```

The problem is that this code doesn't align the table columns properly. How can I make sure all the entries are aligned with each other?

I'd also like to export my data in CSV format so that other programs can read it, but that's a separate question.

Comment: i just use this code
def dvdprintsoftlist():
    print(list_of_DVDsoftwears)
    ''' printing the available DVDstocks,supplier's details '''
    print("This is your current list of stock")
    print("Supplier Name      Softwear Name             Amount")
    print("----------------------------------------------------------------")
    for (index,[name,softname,amount]) in enumerate (list_of_DVDsuppliers):
        print(name + "          " +softname + "            " +str(amount)  + "   ")
        print("----------------------------------------------------------------")
    print("")

Comment: Have you found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9535954/python-printing-lists-as-tabular-data?

Comment: its nt working its python 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `format()`, the `{i:length}` in string, will be replaced by the parameters, where `i` is an order identifier, and `length` is the "length" of the field.

```
def dvdprintsoftlist():
    list_of_DVDsuppliers=[["a","m",15],["w","p",34]]
    print(list_of_DVDsuppliers)
    print
    ''' printing the available DVDstocks,supplier's details '''
    print("This is your current list of stock")
    print("Supplier Name\t\tSoftwear Name\t\tAmount")
    print("----------------------------------------------------------------")
    for [name, softname, amount] in list_of_DVDsuppliers:
        print("{0:23} {1:23} {2:5}".format(name, softname, amount))
        print("----------------------------------------------------------------")
    print("")

dvdprintsoftlist()
```

Comment: this error appered
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\AAA\Desktop\python almost done\test of module useage.py", line 11, in <module>
    import modulenew
  File "C:\Users\AAA\Desktop\python almost done\modulenew.py", line 263
    print "{0:23} {1:23} {2:5}".format(name, softname, amount)
                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Try this code in a new file. And see how it works, then try to add it to your code.
PS: If it's a SyntaxError you may be writting something incorrect there

Comment: I don't understand, but if you are using python 3.x then make sure your print statement is print("{0:23} {1:23} {2:5}".format(name, softname, amount)) Note the ()

Comment: it works thanks a lot lot christian

and could you help me with this quations also
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19556927/create-a-list-from-a-csv-file-and-edit-and-save-back-data-in-csv-using-python

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19555816/why-does-this-python-input-validation-fail

Answer (score 0):

Try using the padding bits between the % and s while printing

you can use them like...

```
print('%-20s%-20s%-20s'%('supplier name','software name','amount'))
```

-for left padding and +ve(default) for right padding