# How to export data from csv as a list(python 3)

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x

I have a list like this(python 3)

```
my_list = [["xxx","moon",150],["wordq","pop",3]]
```

and i save it on a csv using this code

```
import csv

myfile = open("pppp.csv", 'wb')
with open("pppp.csv", "w", newline='') as myfile:
    wr = csv.writer(myfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    wr.writerows(list_of_DVDsuppliers)
```

now i need to export this csv in to my program as a list and change the data .
please help me ?

Comment: Did you save it to a single line because you want to flatten the list?

Comment: its saved like this
xxx,moon,150
wordq , pop ,3

Comment: Yeah, but why? You must've had some purpose.

Comment: ya if its not csv file store data skiping 1 row

Answer (score 1):

Just convert the data you get from reader() to a list:

```
data = csv.reader(open('example.csv','r'))
data = list(data)
print data
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a reason why you are using newline='', you can skip that and below code works with python 2.7,

```
import csv

my_list = [["xxx","moon",150],["wordq","pop",3]]

myfile = open("pppp.csv", 'wb')
with open("pppp.csv", "w") as myfile:
    wr = csv.writer(myfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    wr.writerows(my_list)


data = csv.reader(open('pppp.csv','r'))
for row in data:
    print row
```

Comment: What about the `newline=''` part?

Comment: i dont no about that.cos my friend teach me to do so,and is ther's a way to restore csv data(when i re open my program) in my_list ?

Comment: and this error occurs to your code

data = csv.reader(open('pppp.csv,'r'))
                                         ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

Comment: I do not see an option of newline in 2.7 anyway.

Comment: nop not working its python 3.3

and really me need is when i restart the progam i want to restore the csv data in my_list?

Comment: Did you try replacing open("pppp.csv", "w") in my code with open("pppp.csv", "w", newline='') and open('pppp.csv','r') with ("pppp.csv", "r", newline='')? If it's working for you while writing then probably should work while reading as well in 3.3.

Comment: problem is that I am using python 2.7 and code works with that I won't be able to check with 3.3. Why don't you repost this question but only with python 3.3 tag. And let someone with 3.3 answer this.